# Android localization (invalid resource directory name)

Tags: android, eclipse

Each time I create values_enu folder under res folder in eclipse for localization issue  I get an error   invalid resource directory name

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Can someone help please.

Comment: What is "enu"?? It must be "en". And it should be "values-en" instead of "values_en".

Comment: This is totally wrong. You need to use `values-enu` instead of `values_enu`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only should write "values-en".
The syntax is: FOLDERNAME **MINUS** 2-CHARACTER-LANGUAGE-KEY

Another example:

drawable-es <<= this will create a folder for Spanish picture files. It could be useful for implementing a labeled button you have created in photoshop or gimp.

Answer (score 8):

One thing that wasn't clear to me from the docs is what a directory should be called in case of language variants, e.g. British/American English or German/Austrian German.

So even though the locales are of form `en_GB`, `en_US`, `de_DE` or `de_AT` etc, the corresponding folders should be called

```
res/values-en-rGB/
res/values-en-rUS/
res/values-de-rDE/
res/values-de-rAT/
```

That means keep the letter capitalization but use only hyphens instead of underscores and add an `r` before the language variant.

Comment: Is there any documentation about it ?

Answer (score 1):

Use hyphen(-) instead of underscores(_)..

values-en is valid and values_en is invalid